# How to convert image to integer array? (do not use any non-standard library)

Tags: image, image-processing

How to convert image.png or image.bmp to integer array? (do not use any non-standard library)

Please ignore chunks that are not directly related to image data.(IHDR、IEND...etc.)

thank you very much.

SOLVED: I should use binary I/O function in stdio.h to read image file. thanks

Comment: you cannot read a png file when you ingore all chunks...

Comment: thanks, I already corrected.

Comment: Which language, and is a standard library/class allowed? .png is compressed so would need something. .bmp is memory hungry and has many variations (you need structural info).

Comment: any language is okay. I just want to know how does it work.

Comment: Alternatively, how to convert binary image file to integer array?

Comment: please ignore any fancy function, like compression...

Answer (score 0):

If you have to read images into arrays without any image processing libraries you need two things:

You need means to read files in general.

You need to know the internal structure of the file formats you want to read.

So for png refer to https://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-PNG-20031110/

This document will tell you where to find the image dimensions, pixel data and other features. It's basically a manual for software developers on how to use this standard format properly.

Some image formats will require additional work like decrompression.

Comment: yes, I did. Although image data chunk appear when I use hex editor to open image file, it is represented by hexadecimal.

Comment: I got it. I should use binary I/O function in stdio.h  to read image file. thanks.

Comment: @RockyTseng a hex editor shows binary data as Hexadecimals because FF AB C6 is easier to read and edit than 111111111010101111000110. the specification tells you which bytes do what. all you need to do is read the right bytes, cast them to integer and put them into an array. (in the simplest case)